# Exercise 3 in Section 7.11 of Apostol's Calculus (Vol. 1) little o-notation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, trigonometry

The problem is stated as:

> Find the polynomial $P(x)$ of minimal degree such that
>   $$
> \sin(x-x^2)=P(x)+o(x^6)\quad \textrm{as }x\to 0.
> $$

and the answer in the book is

> $$
> P(x)=x-x^2-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{2}-\frac{59x^5}{120}+\frac{x^6}{8}
> $$

I am wondering why the answer cannot be

$P(x) = x-x^2$

Since we can use the fact that $\sin(x-x^2) = x-x^2 + o((x-x^2)^2)$ as $x \to 0$

And we know that $o((x-x^2)^2) = o(x^5) = o(x^6)$ as $x$ goes to zero.

Then why is the answer from the back of the book not equal to $x-x^2$??

Comment: That is because, when you compose an expansion by another expansion, they must have the same degree of expansion.

Comment: No: $o((x-x^2)^2) = o(x^2)$. Where did you get the idea that it is $o(x^5)$ and that $o(x^5)$ is $o(x^6)$? To be explicit, $(x-x^2)^2 = x^2(1-2x+x^2) = x^2 + o(x^2)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin by the definition, we know that $o(x^5)=x^9$ as x goes to zero(random choose, just so that the power is greater than 6), then again by the def we have $o(x^6)=x^9$ hence $o(x^5)=o(x^6)$ as x goes to zero, can you tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: This is not equality in the sense you're thinking. Both $x^6$ and $x^7 \sin x$ are $o(x^5)$. Does that make them equal? Better review definitions of $o$.

Comment: @TedShifrin That's why I'm confused, in the book, the definition is stated so. Namely: If $g(x)\neq0$ for all $x\neq$ a in some interval containing a. The notation $f(x)=o(g(x))$ as x goes to a means that $f(x)/g(x)$ goes to 0 as x goes to a. Is there any thing I missed here?

Comment: That's correct. Now go back to what you wrote and see if it works.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand, is the  " = " sign here the same with the equal sign we usually use? It's a bit weird since usually Apostol would say, $f(x)\rightarrow o(g(x))\,as\, x \rightarrow a$ but here he uses $f(x)=o(g(x))\,as\, x \rightarrow a$.

Comment: No, we never use the arrow with $o$ or $O$ notation. But note that if $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ are both $o(g(x))$, we cannot compare $f(x)$ and $F(x)$. Write out the limit definitions and try!

Comment: @TedShifrin So does $f(x)=o(g(x))\:as\:x \rightarrow a$ means the same as $f(x) \rightarrow o(g(x))\:as\: x \rightarrow a$?

Comment: I just said: No one ever writes an arrow with the little $o$. Every time you see the $o$ notation, translate it into the limit definition on your paper.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks I get your point, but then another problem shows up if we use the limit definition alone, without using the equality "=" how can we show $o(g(x))+o(g(x))=o(g(x))$? . The proof in the book uses the fact that $o(g(x))=a(x)$ and $o(g(x))=b(x)$, then proving $a(x)+b(x)=o(g(x)$. But isn't this means we can also do, $o(x)=x^3=o(x^2)$? (By using the equality of "=").

Comment: The answer should not contain the term $o(x^6)$ in $P$.

Comment: @Jack Thank you. Sorry I mistyped the answer. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that one has $o(x^6)=o(x^5)$ (as $x\to 0$), but not $o(x^5)=o(x^6)$.

Also, $o((x-x^2)^2)=o(x^5)$ is incorrect: one has $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^5}{(x-x^2)^2}=0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^5}{x^5}=1$. In general, $o(f(x))=o(g(x))$ does NOT imply that $o(g(x))=o(f(x))$ as discussed in an answer to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3270015/9464) of yours.

> Why the answer cannot be $x-x^2$?

It is an instructive exercise to show (using the correct answer in Apostol) that the following is FALSE:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (x-x^2)-(x-x^2)}{x^6}= 0\tag{1}
$$

---

[Added.]
To see why (1) is false, you can use the solution of $P(x)$ in the book
so that
$$\begin{align}
f(x):=\frac{\sin (x-x^2)-(x-x^2)}{x^6}
&=\frac{a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5+a_6x^6+o(x^6)}{x^6}\\
&=\frac{1}{x^3}
\left(
a_3+a_4x+a_5x^2+a_6x^3
\right)+\frac{o(x^6)}{x^6}\\
&=\frac{1}{x^3}\cdot g(x)+h(x)
\end{align}
$$
where $g(x):=a_3+a_4x+a_5x^2+a_6x^3$.

Now, note that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=a_3\neq 0,\quad \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{o(x^6)}{x^6}=0.
$$
So
$
\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=\infty
$
and (1) is thus impossible.

Comment: Could you explain more of your argument here of $o((x-x^2)^2) \neq o(x^5)?$ Thanks! By what I've known now, $o(x^2)=o((x-x^2)^2)$ so it is impossible for the latter to be equal to $o(x^5)$ since $o(x^2) \neq o(x^5)$. But I'm curious of your argument.

Comment: @hteica: do you understand that why $o(x^2)=o(x)$ (as $x\to 0$) but $o(x)\neq o(x^2)$? Again, such equality is "one-direction".

Comment: "$o((x-x^2)^2)=o(x^5)$ as $x\to 0$" means "**if** $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{(x-x^2)^2}=0$, **then** $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^5}=0$. But this is NOT true by the counterexample $f(x)=x^5$.

Comment: By writing out the definition, the first one is no problem, but the second one, I can't show whether it is $=$ or $\neq$. Since $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$ but this doesn't necessarily mean that $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2}=0$.

Comment: **If** $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=0$, **then** $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$. So $o(x^2)=o(x)$ as $x\to 0$ is correct. On the other hand, the example $f(x)=x^2$ shows that $o(x)\neq o(x^2)$ (as $x\to 0$).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've tried do the instructive exercise you mentioned above by trying to find a contradiction by assuming the false to be true. And come to conclusion that $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{6x^3}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{59}{120x}=1/8.$ And we can show that this is wrong and get our desired contradiction by writing out the definition of the limit, is that correct?

Comment: @hteica: see added part.

Answer (score 1):

What they are asking you is to find a polynomial $p(x)$ such that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{|\sin(x-x^2)-p(x)|}{x^6}=0
$$

No to your statements:

1. $o((x-x^2)^2) =o(x^5)$ is in general false. For example $h(x)=x(x-x^2)^2=o((x-x^2)^2$ as $x\rightarrow0$ but $x^{-5}h(x)\nrightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow0$.
2. $o(x^5) = o(x^6)$ is false in general: $g(x):=x^6=o(x^5)$ but $g(x) \neq o(x^6)$.

To help you solve the problem, use Taylor expansion of $\sin z= z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+...$. Notice that when $z=x-x^2$, $z^7$ is a polynomial on $x$ of degree 14 of the $z^7=x^7-7x^8+...-x^{14}$ This term is of course $o(x^6)$ since all powers involved are larger than $6$. So truncating the sine series up to the $7-th$ power gives the right decay of residual. The rest is to check that the 
$$
(x-x^2)-\frac{(x-x^2)^3}{6}+\frac{(x-x^2)^5}{5!}
$$
is the polynomial in the statement of your problem. A little but tedious algebra.

Comment: Why do you think that $o((x-x^2)^2) = o(x^5)$? We're talking about $x\to 0$, not $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Taylor expansion is not yet introduced in the book so I don't think we are "allowed" to use them.

Comment: Then you may have to use L'hospital rule to estimate the limit I mentioned in the second line.

Comment: @OliverDiaz L'hospital rule is not yet proven, since limit infinity is not yet defined.

Answer (score 1):

*A sketch of the correct method*:

Since $x-x^2$ has order $1$, you have to expand $\sin u$ up to degree $6$, and substitute $x-x^2$ in $u, u^2,\dots u^6$, truncating the expansions of the different $(x-x^2)^k$ at degree $6$, which leads to a recursive computation:
\begin{align}
(x-x^2)^2&=x^2-2x^3+x^4& \quad(x-x^2)^3&=x^3-3x^4+3x^5-x^6 \\
(x-x^2)^4&=x^4-4x^5+6x^6-4x^7+x^8&(x-x^2)^5&=(x-x^2)^4(x-x^2)\\
&=x^4-4x^5+6x^6+o(x^6)&&=\bigl((x^4-4x^5+6x^6+o(x^6)\bigr)(x-x^2)\\
(x-x^2)^6&=(x-x^2)^5(x-x^2)&&=\begin{aligned}[t]&x^5-4x^6+6x^7+o(x^7)\\&\phantom{x5}-x^6+4x^7-6x^8+o(x^8)
&\end{aligned}\\&=\bigl(x^5-5x^6+o(x^6)\bigr)(x-x^2)&&=x^5-5x^6+o(x^6)\\
&=\dots=x^6+o(x^6)
\end{align}

Can you end the computations?