# Property of the little-o notation in Calculus Apostol

Tags: calculus, limits, notation, definition

The definition of little $o$ in Calculus Apostol book is stated as:

[image]

From this definition, we can say that, $as\: x \rightarrow 0$ we have

$o(x^2)=x^3 \quad and\quad  o(x)=x^3.$

which means that $o(x^2)=x^3=o(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. We could even proceed to show that
$o(x^2)=o(x^3)=o(x^4)=...=o(x^n)$ by letting them all equal to $x^m$ where $m>n$.

But then, for example, if we let $o(x^2)=f(x)$ as $x\rightarrow a$, we cannot proceed to show that $f(x)=o(x^3)$ since we would have show that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/x^3=0$$

and we know that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/x^2=0$$.

Which is not going so well. So is something wrong here?

Is the $=$ sign in the definition $f(x)=o(g(x))$ really the same with the $=$ we usually use?

Comment: The notation $o(g)$ strictly speaking should be understood as "the set of all functions $f$ such that $f/g\to 0$" and $f=o(g)$ should be understood as $f\in o(g)$. Then your confusion does not arise.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Does $o(g(x))+o(g(x))=o(g(x))$ mean also $o(g(x))+o(g(x)) \in o(g(x))$? If $o(g(x))$ is a set, then does  $o(g(x))+o(g(x))$ mean $o(g(x))\cup o(g(x))$? If we use this definition, how could we prove the statement $o(g(x))+o(g(x))=o(g(x))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From this definition, we can say that, $as\: x \rightarrow 0$ we have
>
> $o(x^2)=x^3 \quad and\quad  o(x)=x^3.$

**NO!**
One should be careful that the expression $f(x)=o(g(x))$ in the definition can **NOT** be written as $o(g(x))=f(x)$.

Whenever, one sees the expression $f(x)=o(g(x))$ (as $x\to a$), it means *nothing* but
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\tag{*}
$$

There are some subtleties when the notation $o(g(x))$ appears in different places of an expression.

(1) $f(x)=o(g(x))$ as in the definition means the function $f(x)$ on the left has the property $(*)$. The symbol $=$ here is not the usual "equal" sign.

(2) when $o(g(x))$ appears in an expression like $1+o(x^2)$, it simply means any *instance* of functions that has property $(*)$.

(3) A combination of (1) and (2). For example, the meanings of different $o(x^2)$ in an "equality" like expression
$$
x^3+o(x^2)=o(x^2),\quad \textrm{as  } x\to 0
$$
are different. On the left, $o(x^2)$ is understood as in (2) and thus $x^3+o(x^2)$ is a function; one the right, it means that the function on the left has the property $(*)$ with $g(x)=x^2$ and $a=0$.

(4) $o(x^3)=o(x^2)$ (as $x\to 0$) is a correct statement but $o(x^2)=o(x^3)$ is not:

if $f(x)$ is such that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}=0$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=0$; but not the other way around. See also the discussion in Wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Matters_of_notation

Comment: For example, to prove the statement $f(x)o(g(x))=o(f(x)g(x))$, we work from left to right, namely, we introduce a function $h(x)$ to replace $o(g(x))$ with the property $(*)$. But does this really mean the other way around? namely: $o(f(x)g(x))=f(x)o(g(x))$. Don't we need to prove this other way once more?

Comment: @hteica No. The expression like $o(f(x)g(x))=f(x)o(g(x))$ does *not* make sense just as one would write $x^3=o(x^2)$ but NOT $o(x^2)=x^3$. Knuth describes such statements as "one-way equalities", since if the sides could be reversed "we could deduce ridiculous things" like $x^3 = x^4$ from the identities x^3 = o(x^2) and $x^4 = o(x^2)$. (See also the link above.) Whenever $o(g(x))$ appears on the right hand side of the "=" sign, it simply describes the limiting *property* of the function on the left and "=" should NOT be understood as what we have in the "usual" sense.

Comment: @hteica: See also (4) above.

Comment: But in your answer from another question, you used the identity $o(f(x)g(x))=f(x)o(g(x))$ instead of the other way. If $=$ is "one way equality", are we allowed to do this flipping?

Comment: @hteica: I made a mistake in that answer and I have edited the proof.

Comment: I'm wondering where does the property (2) come from? Is it defined that way? In the book the definition only states the property (1).

Comment: @hteica: (2) is more a "convention" than a "definition". That's how one would *interpret* an expression like $x^3+o(x^2)$ (as $x \to 0$): it means one adds the function $x^3$ with *some* function $f$ that has the property $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=0$.

Comment: Do you mean like, the motivation of defining little oh has resulted in this convention? I kind of get it but am not really sure, this definition is to neglect the unnecessary details, right?

Comment: @hteica: more or less. This is an example of "[abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation)", which happens a lot in mathematics.

Comment: I see, so asymptotic notation is one of the example of the "abuse of notation". Thank you very much for explaining all these things! I've understood it much better now.

Answer (score 4):

The use of the equal sign in $f(x)=o(g(x))$ is a sometimes-convenient convention. That equal sign doesn’t indicate that this is a “real” identity any more than the dot product in the mnemonic formula $\nabla\cdot f$ for $\operatorname{div}f$ is a “real” dot product. Treating it as such can get you into trouble, as the many times someone has asked about the difference between $f\cdot\nabla$ and $\nabla\cdot f$ on this site will attest.

In particular, this “equality” is not transitive. As was mentioned in a comment, $o(g(x))$ is properly the set of all functions that satisfy the criteria in the quoted definition. Loosely speaking they are the functions that vanish “faster” than $g(x)$ as $x\to a$. The expression  $f(x)=o(g(x))$ really means $f(x) \in o(g(x))$. If you have $x^3\in o(x^2)$ and $x^3\in o(x)$, you can conclude that $o(x)\cap o(x^2)\ne\emptyset$, but not that these two sets are identical. Indeed, $x^2 \in o(x)$, but obviously $x^2\notin o(x^2)$. For brevity we often say “$f(x)$ **is** little-oh of $g(x)$” instead of “$f(x)$ is a member of little-oh of $g(x)$,” which could be how writing $=$ instead of $\in$ came into use.

When you see the term $o(g(x))$ as part of some expression, it’s a shorthand for “some unknown function $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(x)\in o(g(x))$.” Each instance of this term potentially stands for a different function. So, in particular, the expression $o(g(x))+o(g(x))$ in your comment to the question really means $$\varphi(x)+\psi(x), \text{ where } \varphi(x),\psi(x)\in o(g(x)),$$ with the identities of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ otherwise left unspecified. With this understanding, the addition rule $o(g(x))+o(g(x))=o(g(x))$ really means that for any two functions $\varphi(x), \psi(x)\in o(g(x))$, $\varphi(x)+\psi(x)\in o(g(x))$ (i.e., the sum of two functions that vanish faster than $g(x)$ also vanishes faster than $g(x)$). The proof of the expanded statement is trivial.

Comment: So we could say that, for example, $o(x^4) \rightarrow 0 \quad as \quad x \rightarrow 0 \: ?$ Since we could choose some function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)/x^4 \rightarrow 0 \quad as \quad x \rightarrow 0.$ Is this correct? This seems to make sense, but I am just making sure. If we are able this, then we could always make the $o(g(x))$ gone, but then would you kindly explain what's the point of this little oh-notation if we can just make them disappear??

Comment: @HteicaVlidel That’s not really how asymptotic notations are used. The point isn’t that functions that are $o(x^4)$ tend toward $0$, it’s how fast they do so compared to other functions. Both little-oh and big-oh bound the function from above, but in different ways. They also hide irrelevant detail, making calculations and proofs much simpler. See, for example, [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2627671/265466) of the chain rule for differentials.

Comment: I see, so asymptotic notations are used to neglect the irrelevant details. Would you also kindly confirm this following manipulation, $o(o(x^3)+\frac{1}{2}x^2) + o(x^3) = o(o(x))+o(x^3)=o(x) +o(x^3)=o(x) \: $ Is this true? But in the exercise the result is $o(x^2)$. I'm wondering where I did wrong.