# To show that $o(o(x^3)-\frac{1}{2}x^2)-o(x^3)=o(x^2) \: as \: x \rightarrow 0.$ Apostol Calculus Example 1 pg.288

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, asymptotics

I encounter this problem when I was trying to show that

$\sec x=1+\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2) \: as \: x \rightarrow 0.$

We know that $\cos x=1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^3).$

So $\sec x=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^3)} = 1+\frac{1}{2}x^2-o(x^3)+o(o(x^3)-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$

In the the book Calculus Apostol, it states that the the two little o's behind is equal to $o(x^2)$ without an explanation.

I could prove that they equal to $o(x)$ since

$-o(x^3)+o(o(x^3)-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$

$= -o(x^3)+o(o(x^3)-o(x))$

$= -o(x^3)+o(o(x^3)+o(x)) = -o(x^3)+o(o(x))=o(x)+o(x^3)=o(x).$

But is this correct, if then how can it equal $o(x^2)$?

Comment: $o(-\frac12x^2)=o(x^2)$, not $o(x)$.

Comment: Should have $-o(x^3)+o(o(x^3)-\frac{1}{2}x^2)= -o(x^3)+o(o(x^3)-o(x^2))$ instead.

Comment: I wonder why the precision is that bad. If you use $\frac1{1-g(x)}=1+g(x)+g(x)^2+o(g(x^2))$, you get the same error order $o(x^3)$ back that you put in.

Comment: @Jack as x goes to 0, the limit of $\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x^2}$ is 1/2 and not 0.

Comment: You have $f\in o(-\frac12x^2)$ if $2x^{-2}f(x)\to 0 $ for $x\to 0$. This however is the same as $f\in o(x^2)$.

Comment: @hteica: Please check Theorem 7.8 (b) in your book: $o(cg(x))=o(g(x))$ if $c\neq 0$.

Comment: @LutzL But then how is that justify that $o(x^2)=\frac{1}{2}x^2?$

Comment: @Jack Could you explain why $o(x^2)=\frac{1}{2}x^2?$ By the definition of the little o, this just doesn't fit.

Comment: @hteica: it is $o(\frac12x^2)=o(x^2)$, NOT $\frac12x^2=o(x^2)$.

Comment: Why should it? That $o(o(x^2))\subset o(x^2)$ does not imply that $x^2\in o(x^2)$.

Comment: @Jack but there is still $o(x^3)$ inside the little oh, where does it go?

Comment: @LutzL I know but how does it explain the problem?

Comment: You have that $o(x^2+o(x^3))=x^2o(1+o(x))$ and as $o(x)$ is bounded you get $o(1+o(x))=o(1)$, so that the original expression is $o(x^2)$.

Comment: @LutzL What do you mean by "bounded"? Does this manipulation decrease the precision?

Comment: No, it does not decrease the order, as that depends on the dominant term. And in that sense, $x^2\gg o(x^2)\gg o(x^3)$, so the last is really negligible against the first, in the exact definition it can be captured by increasing some (implicitly contained) constants slightly. Note that $x$ is per definition constrained to some small interval around $0$.

Comment: @LutzL which one is the dominant term, do you mean $x^2$? And what does it mean for little oh to be bounded like $o(1+o(x))$?

Comment: $f(x)\in o(x^2+o(x^3))$ can be interpreted as $f(x)=(x^2+x^3r_2(x))r_1(x^2+x^3r_2(x))$ with $r_1(0)=r_2(0)=0$ and both functions continuous in $0$. Obviously, $x^{-2}f(x)=(1+xr_2(x))r_1(x^2+x^3r_2(x))\to 0$ for $x\to 0$.

Comment: @LutzL Sorry but I don't understand. Why can we interpret them that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to understand in Example 1 that
$$
\frac{1}{\cos x}=\frac{1}{1-\frac12x^2+o(x^3)}=1+\frac12 x^2+o(x^2)
\quad\textrm{as }x\to 0.
$$

Apostol says that this is "from part (e) of Theorem 7.8", i.e.,

> As $x\to a$, if $g(x)\to 0$, then
>   $$
> \frac{1}{1+g(x)}={1-g(x)+o(g(x))}.
> $$

So if you let $g(x)=-\frac12x^2+o(x^3)$, then
$$
\sec x 
= 1-(-\frac12x^2+o(x^3))+o(-\frac12x^2+o(x^3))
=1+\frac12x^2-o(x^3)+o(-\frac12x^2+o(x^3)).
$$

Note that $-o(x^3)=o(-x^3)=o(x^3)$ by Theorem 7.8 (c) and (b). Also,
$$
o(-\frac12x^2+o(x^3))=o(x^2).
$$

Hence, 
$$
\sec x = 1+\frac12 x^2+o(x^3)+o(x^2)
=1+\frac12 x^2+o(x^2).
$$

---

[Added.] To see why $o(-\frac12x^2+o(x^3))=o(x^2)$, suppose $f(x)=o(-\frac12x^2+h(x))$ for some $h$ with $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)}{x^3}=0$. Then by definition, 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{-\frac12x^2+h(x)}=0.\tag{1}
$$

We want to show that $f(x)=o(x^2)$, i.e.,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=0.\tag{2}
$$

But
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{-\frac12x^2+h(x)}\cdot
\frac{-\frac12x^2+h(x)}{x^2}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{-\frac12x^2+h(x)}\cdot
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac12x^2+h(x)}{x^2}=0.
$$

Comment: What I don't understand is why $o(\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^3))=o(x^2)+o(o(x^3).$ Could you explain it more detail how you used the theorems in this step?

Comment: @hteica: see the added part.

Comment: I'm wondering how do you know $xh(x)o(x^2)=o(x^2)$, did you do it by writing out the definition?

Comment: @hteica: yes, that simply follows from the definition and the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)=0$.

Comment: Is it allowed to factor out $x^2$ from the little o? Since from what I read, the $=$ sign is just really a $\subseteq$, so it shouldn't work both ways.

Comment: @hteica: No, you are not factoring anything but just using the definition. Note that $F(x):=xh(x)o(x^2)$ can be written as $F(x)=xh(x)\cdot{G(x)}$ for some $G(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{G(x)}{x^2}=0$ by the *definition* of $o(x^2)$. Now you can show by definition that $F(x)=o(x^2)$, i.e., $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x)}{x^2}=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped, not factoring out $x^2$ but factoring out $p(x)$. Are we allowed to do this? why?

Comment: That is not "factoring" either, See Theorem 7.8 (c).

Comment: Yes I know you were using Theorem 7.8 (c). But we proved it to be "one way" since from what I read the $=$ is just really $\subseteq$. So it cannot go the other way.

Comment: The notation $o(g(x))$ is not quite a set. And $f(x)=o(g(x))$ should not be understood as $f(x)\in o(g(x))$ either. Otherwise, it does not make sense to write something like $x^3+o(x^2)$ since one can not add an element and a set. Likewise $f(x)\cdot o(g(x))=o(f(x)g(x))$ is not a "set equality". It is interpreted as follows: for *any* $h(x)=o(g(x))$, one has $f(x)h(x)=o(f(x)g(x))$, i.e., if $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}=0$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)h(x)}{f(x)g(x)}=0$.

Comment: I see, so it was defined that way. Then what is $o(g(x))$, is it a function?

Comment: @hteica: see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3271837/9464

Comment: In the last line, $o(p(x)x^2)=p(x)o(x^2)$, are we allowed to do this? Shouldn't it be the other way around? namely: $p(x)o(x^2)=o(p(x)x^2).$

Comment: In this case, I've tried prove the other way around and it works, but in the case like $o(g(x))+o(g(x))=o(g(x))$, is it true the other way around? namely: $o(g(x))=o(g(x))+o(g(x))$

Comment: @hteica: good catch. You are correct that one should not write $o(p(x)x^2)=p(x)o(x^2)$. I have edited the proof. Similarly, one should not write $o(g(x))=o(g(x))+o(g(x))$.

Comment: I think this case it works, I've tried to prove that $o(f(x)g(x))=f(x)o(g(x))$ and it's shown to be true, so you can use it in the proof. But in the case $o(g(x))=o(g(x))+o(g(x))$, I don't think it works.

Comment: @hteica: well, if $o(f(x)g(x))=f(x)o(g(x))$ (as $x\to 0$) makes sense, then it means the following. Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x)}{f(x)g(x)}=0$, then $F(x)=f(x)G(x)$ with some $G$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{G(x)}{g(x)}=0$. Indeed OK since one can write $G(x):=\frac{F(x)}{f(x)}$. It is just that I believe one rarely writes $o(f(x)g(x))=f(x)o(g(x))$ in practice.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, could you read in the question how I found out that those little o's are equal to $o(x)$, is it correct? Since if they are equal to $o(x^2)$, they are also equal to $o(x)$ so no contradiction here. Right?

Comment: @hteica: $o(g(x))=o(g(x))+o(g(x))$, if it makes sense, is not very interesting. Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$. One can simply write $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=\frac12 f(x)$. Then $f=f_1+f_2$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f_i(x)}{g(x)}=0$, $i=1,2$.

Comment: Your calculation is correct and you are correct that no contradiction here. Note for instance that both "$x^3=o(x)$" and "$x^3=o(x^2)$" are correct.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear to me now!

Comment: @Jack, I am not sure the last proof is valid - the term $-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + h(x)$ can be zero infinite amount of times as $x \rightarrow 0$ when $h(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$, so it is not allowed to divide/multiply by this expression in the limit.

Comment: @John: Note that $h= o(x^3)$. What do you mean by "can be zero infinite amount of times"?

Comment: @Jack, I mean that $h(x)$ can be $h(x_i) = \frac{1}{2}x_i^2$ for infinite amount of times ($i \in \mathbb{N}$), while $x \rightarrow 0$, so the division by $-\frac{1}{2}x_i^2 + h(x_i) = 0$ is invalid.

Comment: @John: No, it can't be that case since $h=o(x^3)$.

Comment: @Jack, why not? $h = o(x^3)$ says that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{h}{x^3} = 0$, but it does not preclude $h$ from hitting zero while the quotient is converging to 0 in the limit, right? $h$ can be some function like $x\sin(1/x)$

Comment: @John: "it does not preclude ℎ from hitting zero" true. But it preclude *the way* "ℎ from hitting zero". "ℎ can be some function like". No, it can't be: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\sin(1/x)}{x^3}$ does not exist.

Comment: @Jack, sry, i did not get "preclude the way ..." argument. Could you clarify that? Or can it be shown formally somehow? The function limit $x\sin(1/x)$ divided by $x^3$ does not exist at $0$, but what if there is other similar function $f(x)$: $f(x)$ intersects the x-axis infinite times while going to zero limit, AND having the property $f(x) = o(x^3)$.

Comment: @John: I have to leave now. l suggest you post a question with appropriate contexts on the main site. That would be a good question to ask. Others may quickly respond.

Comment: Thx @Jack, if interested, it is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335562/proof-of-a-little-o-property