# Proof of a little-o property

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, proof-verification, asymptotics

Little-o has the following property:

$$o(o(g(x))) = o(g(x))$$

I prove it like this. Let $f_1(x) = o(g(x)), f_2(x) = o(f_1(x))$. Then the statement $o(o(g(x)))$ implies $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_2(x)}{f_1(x)} = 0$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)} = 0$. We need to prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_2(x)}{g(x)} = 0$.

We can use $$\lim \frac{f_2(x)}{g(x)} = \lim \frac{f_2(x)}{f_1(x)}\frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)} =  \lim \frac{f_2(x)}{f_1(x)}\lim \frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)} = 0\;\; (*)$$ (all limits as $x \rightarrow 0$).

Is this a valid proof? The issue here is that the division by $f_1$ in the denominator of $(*)$ might be prohibited, since it can be that $f_1(x) = 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. Otherwise, is there anything else wrong with this proof?

Comment: You could try using the following definition of $o$ : Let be $f : U \longmapsto \mathbb{R},x_{0}$ accumulation point of $f$. We say that $f = o(g(x)) \hspace{0.2cm} x \to x_{0}$ If exists $\epsilon : U \longmapsto \mathbb{R} : f(x) = \epsilon(x) \cdot g(x), \hspace{0.3cm} \lim\limits_{x \to x_{0}} \epsilon(x) = 0$

Comment: @jacopoburelli, I have not read a book on topology yet, so im limited to the basic definitions (no accumulation points yet which I have just looked up in Wiki) :) I am solving Apostol calculus which is real analysis on real numbers (the property is from there too - page 288), and he has not given me any definition of accumulation points yet (he discusses those in his mathematical analysis text though).

Comment: Limits adcquires sense only in accumulation points, otherwise,like in isolated points,you lose its uniqueness and the notation $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ omitting where $x$ ''tends'' to evaluate if $f(x)=o(g(x))$, is misunderstandable to me, because $o$ as mentioned is firstly defined when $x \to x_{0}$ . We can almost say that being $o$ is not a general property but rather local, as limits are

Comment: @jacopoburelli, the limit point here always is $0$, so should be no ambiguity :) But in general, it should always be specified which $a$ $x$ tends to right?

Comment: Yes i think it's always better to specify, i didn't mean to correct just suggesting another way to approach the exercises since solving with limits you're implicitly using points of accumulations

Comment: Where (which book) is the statement mentioned at the beginning of your post from?

Comment: @Jack, Theorem 7.8 (d), Apostol Calculus 1, second international edition, page 288. Proof omitted as trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that in [Apostol's Calculus I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471000051) (mentioned in comment by OP), the little o notation is defined as follows (page 286)

> [image]

Whenever one writes $o(h(x))$ (as $x\to a$), it should be understood by context that $h(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\neq a$ in some interval containing $a$. So the statement
$$
o(o(g(x)))=o(g(x)),\quad \textrm{as }x\to a
$$
should be understood as follows:

> Assume that $g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\neq a$ in some interval containing $a$. Suppose $f(x)=o(g(x))$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\neq a$ in some interval containing $a$. Then $o(f(x))=o(g(x))$.

So when you write $f_2(x)=o(f_1(x))$ (as $x\to 0$), you are implicitly assuming by definition of the little o notation that $f_1(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\neq0$ in some interval containing $0$.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I've been looking for!!! Seems like I have terrible attention to detail - I never even remembered this part of the definition where Apostol makes the condition that $g(x)$ should not be zero in the neighbourhood of $a$. Feels good to understand this detail now - thanks again :)